# Sort a list of String with completely custom multiple rules

Tags: java, comparator

I have an List of strings like this: **[8****, 7****, 73***, ****1, **101, *4101, 12010 etc]**

And I want to sort with the following 2 rules.

- First rule: Using only the last number / asterisks , the sorted
  should be:   first asterisks, then numbers 1-9 and then 0.
- Second rule: Using the second from last character the sorting should be: first asterisks , then numbers 0-9.

so the final array should become : **[7****, 8**** , 73***, 320** , ****1 , **101, 12101]**

I have created a custom Comparator and I get each char individually:

```
public class MyCustomComparator implements Comparator<ObjToCompare> {


@Override
public int compare(ObjToCompare o1, ObjToCompare o2) {


    String lastSubstr1 = o1.getMyString.substring(o1.getMyString.length()-1);
    String lastSubstr2 = o2.getMyString.substring(o2.getMyString.length()-1);

    String secondFromLastSubstr1 =o1.getMyString.substring(o1.getMyString.length()-2,o1.getMyString().length()-1);
    String secondFromLastSubstr2 =o2.getMyString.substring(o2.getMyString.length()-2,o2.getMyString().length()-1);

    String thirdFromLastSubstr1 = o1.getMyString.substring(o1.getMyString.length()-3,o1.getMyString().length()-2);
    String thirdFromLastSubstr2 = o2.getMyString.substring(o2.getMyString.length()-3,o2.getMyString().length()-2);

    String fourthFromLastSubstr1 = o1.getMyString.substring(o1.getMyString.length()-4,o1.getMyString().length()-3);
    String fourthFromLastSubstr2 = o2.getMyString.substring(o2.getMyString.length()-4,o2.getMyString().length()-3);

    String fifthFromLastSubstr1 = o1.getMyString.substring(o1.getMyString.length()-5,o1.getMyString().length()-4);
    String fifthFromLastSubstr2 = o2.getMyString.substring(o2.getMyString.length()-5,o2.getMyString().length()-4);




    int last =  lastSubstr1.compareTo(lastSubstr2);



    return lastSubstr1.compareTo(lastSubstr2);
}}
```

How can I implement the above logic? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the two rules given are the _only_ rules by which you want to sort? For example, you have "8****" and "7****" changing places in the sorted result,  However, considering just their last and next-to-last characters, "8****"=="7****", so it would be wrong to _expect_ them to sort in the order "7****","8****"".  Unless, that is, there are some additional rules you're not telling us about....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it: create two `String`s (for the two rules). each `String` holds the characters in the order set by the rule. For example:

```
String rule1Order = "*1234567890";
```

now the index of the character in the String can be regarded as numeric order value. the difference between the indexes is the desired `compareTo` result:

```
int lastSubstr1Ordervalue = rule1Order.indexOf(lastSubstr1); 
int lastSubstr2Ordervalue = rule1Order.indexOf(lastSubstr2); 
int lastSubstrCompareTo = lastSubstr1Ordervalue - lastSubstr2Ordervalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the full custom comparator for reference:

```
public class MyCustomComparator implements Comparator<ObjToCompare> {

//the custom rules
public static final String SORT_ACCORDING_LAST_RULE = "*1234567890";
public static final String SORT_ACCORDING_SECOND_TO_LAST_RULE = "*0123456789";

@Override
public int compare(ObjToCompare o1, ObjToCompare o2) {


      //get the last char
      String lastSubstr1 = o1.getMyString.substring(o1.getMyString.length()-1);
      String lastSubstr2 = o2.getMyString.substring(o2.getMyString.length()-1);

      int lastSubstr1stOrderValue = SORT_ACCORDING_LAST_RULE.indexOf(lastSubstr1);
      int lastSubstr2ndOrderValue = SORT_ACCORDING_LAST_RULE.indexOf(lastSubstr2);
      int lastSubstrCompareTo = lastSubstr1stOrderValue - lastSubstr2ndOrderValue;

      if (lastSubstrCompareTo == 0) { //if the last digit is the same, sort with the second to last digit

            //get the second from last char
              String secondFromLastSubstr1 =o1.getMyString.substring(o1.getMyString.length()-2,o1.getMyString().length()-1);
              String secondFromLastSubstr2 =o2.getMyString.substring(o2.getMyString.length()-2,o2.getMyString().length()-1);

            int secondFromLastSubstr1stOrderValue = SORT_ACCORDING_SECOND_TO_LAST_RULE.indexOf(secondFromLastSubstr1);
            int secondFromLastSubstr2ndOrderValue = SORT_ACCORDING_SECOND_TO_LAST_RULE.indexOf(secondFromLastSubstr2);

            return secondFromLastSubstr1stOrderValue - secondFromLastSubstr2ndOrderValue;
      } else {
            return lastSubstr1stOrderValue - lastSubstr2ndOrderValue;
        }
}}
```